# Full Screen iframe in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, seo

I am working SEO on wordpress, my goal is to rent out a page by using iframe to put my clients webpage all over mine, but in wordpress if I use iframe the toolbar and widgets remain there. Is there way of hiding everything and just leaving another web page on top of mine? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please provide some code..

Answer (score 0):

Please note that using an iframe might not contribute much in terms of SEO. Have a read through [this article](http://www.visibilitymagazine.com/how-do-iframes-affect-your-seo). What might be relevant:

> iFrames are merely referencing the content, instead of duplicating it. When robots crawl the site and register the iframe tag, they will attribute the original source with any SEO credit instead of the page using the embedded content – i.e. the page with the iFrame.

That said:

To hide the admin toolbar, either disable it in your profile, via /wp-admin/profile.php. Or do this programmatically (in `functions.php`) with something like:

```
if (!is_admin) {
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

To remove widgets, try following the tutorial on [justintadlock.com](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/06/disable-widget-areas-without-touching-theme-templates), in `functions.php` add something like:

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_all_widgets' );

function disable_all_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {

    $sidebars_widgets = array( false );

    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but im not very expirienced in word press and I dont know how to get to /wp-admin-profile.php, I searched in the wordpress menus and in the C-Panel but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Try to paste that after your WordPress url, e.g.: www.example.com/wp-admin/wp-admin-profile.php. Let me know if you need more help.